# Android TWA Asset link verification works with APK file but not if using AAB

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I made TWA App for PWA in android studio, built APK with signing keys, also uploaded  assetlinks.json to my domain web server. Installed APK to mobile devices, all works great no address bar or errors, signing keys are verified, great!

Next I generated AAB (android bundle) the same way. I now installed the AAB on mobile device it shows asset verification failed, address bar is shown.

Next, I uploaded the AAB to google play to verify the "SHA-256 certificate fingerprint" under "Upload key certificate" it is the same as in my assetlinks.json in web server.

What's the trick here, what else I need to do, can't find any clear information about this issue? Anyways, it's my first app to be published.

The problem is that the Android TWA Asset link verification works with APK file but not if using AAB.

Comment: I suspect that I need to use the key under "App signing key certificate". I can't test it until my app is approved

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: I am experiencing  the same problem. Did you figure out what the issue was? Thank you.